# Administrative processing delay of more than a year

Tags: b1-b2-visas, application-status

I applied for B1/B2 visa in May 2014. Now it is already more than a year later. Exactly after one year, the consulate asked for the updated travel information as the initial travel plans were not applicable after such a long delay. I provided the new travel plan. And again, there is a silence.

Is the consulate just updating the information after one year by asking for updated travel plans or is it a sign that processing may soon to be completed?